# Making a http server in Python

Tags: python, http

Just made a http server handling only file uploading.
Want to add a feature to the http server sharing the file on Get request by a http client.

I have no idea how to show the file to clients. So a client can see it using http://127.0.0.1/filename.avi

In summary

A http client is uploading a file to a http server.

A http client is watching the file through the http server

Answer (score 14):

Python 2:
[SimpleHTTPServer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html#module-SimpleHTTPServer).

`python2 -m SimpleHTTPServer 80`

Python 3:
[http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html).

`python -m http.server 80`

Comment: Should have told that I used HTTPServer and BaseHTTPRequest classes in my project. So want to keep them as it is and add the feature.

Comment: If you already implemented an http server that supports POST, then it should be trivial to implement get, check SimpleHTTPServer's code. check : /usr/lib/python2.6/SimpleHTTPServer.py

Comment: @user518978 if you can upload a file you are almost there. Your server will need to keep track of the uploaded files somehow (presumably you are saving these files somewhere on the filesystem). You could implement a method that when the client requests the root ("GET /") you return a list of files. Then the client can request the particular file you want to stream to it.

Answer (score 2):

for the local server with python I run

```
$ python3 -m http.server 8080
```

inside the folder that contains my index.html. Is there any way (maybe a specific flag) to proxy the requests which can't be resolved locally to a given url?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Flask.  It is very lightweight and probably does most of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

new python would be
python -m http.server [port number]
in the command prompt