# How do I add a KML to an OpenLayers map from a local source?

Tags: javascript, gis, openlayers, kml

I am looking at [this](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/kml-layer.html) example from openlayers themselves.  You can see the source by clicking on the "kml-layer.js" link at the bottom.  The source code when i do this looks like this:

```
var map = new OpenLayers.Map({
    div: "map",
    layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
            "WMS", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0",
            {layers: "basic"}
        ),
        new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "kml/lines.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true, 
                    extractAttributes: true,
                    maxDepth: 2
                })
            })
        })
    ],
    center: new OpenLayers.LonLat(-112.169, 36.099),
    zoom: 11
});
```

It seems that this will only work if sourcing a kml via HTTP, but what if I want to source it from my own hard drive while I work on the map itself? I can't seem to find much documentation on how to do this, can someone help out?

Thanks

Comment: This is not specific to OpenLayers, this is how web browsers work in general - you can only request data via HTTP. You'll need to run an HTTP server locally to explose the arbitrary folder you keep your data in.

Comment: Thanks, kryger, is there a quick and easy way to "trick" a folder into behaving like an HTTP server for testing purposes or is it a lot more in depth than that?

Comment: For quick testing on localhost (i.e. 127.0.0.1) you can use Python's in-build httpserver: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4351601/1240557. Note that exposing this to the outside world would be tricky, you should look at Apache/nginx/lighttpd if you're eventually planning to move your project to production.

Answer (score 0):

While this functionality requires hosting, there is a small work around. If the data is public, and you don't want to use Python, you can create a free google website, and upload the KML to there and direct a link to it. This used to work for me.