# How to create a simple HTTP webserver in python?

Tags: python, webserver

I have designed a rest API with Flask now I want to create a simple web server in python to get and post data. How to create web server in python? I do not want to use curl and localserver 5000

Comment: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080` - This command creates a simple web server on port 8080.

Comment: Are you sure you are asking the correct question? If you want to host the Flask application, you need a WSGI server, not a straight HTTP server. If you are wanting to create a client implemented in Python to issue GET and POST requests against the Flask application, you would want to use httplib/http.client or requests Python modules. The way you have phrased the lead in to your question is confusing.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton I do not want to use WSGI server. I was ask to make make python server instead using curl.

Comment: The curl program is a command line client for making requests. You can't make a Python server out of curl. I suggest you go read this series of posts so you understand what different bits do. Your current descriptions of what you are wanting to do are confusing. https://ruslanspivak.com/lsbaws-part1/

Answer (score 2):

For Linux
Open up a terminal and type:

```
$ cd /home/somedir
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Now your http server will start in port `8000`. You will get the message:

```
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
```

Now open a browser and type the following address:

```
http://your_ip_address:8000
```

You can also access it via:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

or

```
http://localhost:8000
```

Also note:

> If the directory has a file named index.html, that file will be served as the initial file. If there is no index.html, then the files in the directory will be listed.

If you wish to change the port that's used start the program via:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

change the port number to anything you want.

Comment: I want it like WSGI and it just opens the directory. I want it similar func like as it give output on localhost/5000

Answer (score 1):

On python3 the command is `python3 -m http.server`
A Google search would easily lead you to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351601/making-a-http-server-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

To create a simple HTTP webserver in python, use the in-built [SimpleHTTPServer](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html) module as shown below:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8080
```

where 8080 is the port number.

Answer (score 0):

For really simple options, as per the one-liners given. For something that can expand easily in the asyncio framework, this is not a bad start to serve files from the current folder (hence the os.path).

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import web
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join

async def main():
    app = web.Application()
    app.add_routes([
        web.static('/', abspath(join(dirname(__file__))))
    ])
    runner = web.AppRunner(app)
    await runner.setup()
    await web.TCPSite(runner, 'localhost', '8080').start()
    await asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()

asyncio.run(main())
```