# How to create a simple HTTP webserver in python 3 responding to GET request with a generated content?

Tags: python-3.x, httpserver

How do I create a simple HTTP webserver in python 3, that would return a generated content for GET requests?

I checked this question, 
[How to create a simple HTTP webserver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45584453/how-to-create-a-simple-http-webserver-in-python), but the solution proposed will return files, which is not the thing I need.

Instead, my server should respond with a generated response.

I know about frameworks like Flask and Django, but they would be an overkill for me. I need the shortest and the least resource greedy code that will just return generated content for any request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little bit of research, I have come up with this as the simplest possible solution:

```py
from http.server import HTTPServer, BaseHTTPRequestHandler


class MyRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(b'My content')


httpd = HTTPServer(('localhost', 5555), MyRequestHandler)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with the `http` module as shown below:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time

hostname = "localhost"
serverPort = 8080

class Server(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<html><head><title>Python Webserver</title> 
</head>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<body>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("<p>Web server is open!</p>", "utf-8"))
        self.wfile.write(bytes("</body></html>", "utf-8"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostname, serverPort), Server)
    print("Server started http://%s:%s" % (hostname, serverPort))

    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server closed")
    time.sleep(2)
```

This code creates a web server on `http://localhost:8080` and displays some text saying `Web server is open!`.